# How to replace a single character in a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I've got a text file that reads like this:

```
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
###############
```

I've written some code that should move the tracker (is that what it's called?) to the coordinates that you specify:

```
f = open('graphs.txt', 'r+')

while True:
    # TODO: Make an error if X or Y is greater than 15.
    x = input('X = ')
    y = input('Y = ')

    # this thing here finds which character to replace, 
    s = x + y * 16 # this is how far the tracker seeks
    f.seek(s)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to manipulate the single character that the tracker is on. Everything I know how to do with regards to reading and writing files basically involves changing the whole file. Is there a way to replace just a single, specified '#' with a '*'?

EDIT: I figured it out, but now I have a new problem.

Comment: cursor is more appropriate than tracker

Answer (score 2):

You can seek to the position and then alter the file using `read` and `write` commands.

Note however that text files are annoying for this and you should use instead binary files.

The following is a program that creates a file with 256+16 `'#'` chars in it (16 + '\n' x 16) if it's not present and instead "draws" a line with stars `'*'` from `x0`, `y0` to `x1`, `y1` if the file is present.

```
try:
    f = open("draw.txt", "rb+")
except IOError:
    print "File was not present: creating it"
    f = open("draw.txt", "wb+")
    f.write(("#"*16 + "\n") * 16)
```

Note that the file is opened in **binary** mode to avoid problems with random seek/write

```
# Ask coordinates
x0 = int(raw_input("x0: "))
y0 = int(raw_input("y0: "))
x1 = int(raw_input("x1: "))
y1 = int(raw_input("y1: "))

# Line drawing DDA algorithm
dx = abs(x1 - x0)
ix = 1 if x0 < x1 else -1
dy = abs(y1 - y0)
iy = 1 if y0 < y1 else -1
m = max(dx, dy)
cx = cy = m >> 1
```

The above is needed to compute the line slope and the number of pixels to draw, the following is the actual DDA loop:

```
for i in xrange(m + 1):
    if 0 <= x0 < 16 and 0 <= y0 < 16:
        # Valid pixel; draw
        f.seek(y0*17 + x0)
        f.write('*')
    # Move to next pixel
    cx += dx
    if cx >= m:
        cx -= m
        x0 += ix
    cy += dy
    if cy >= m:
        cy -= m
        y0 += iy
```

Note that the code computes the seek position as `y*(16+1)+x`: the extra `1` is for the newline character that is present on each line. Finally the file is closed.

```
# All done
f.close()
```

The following is the content of the file after two runs of the program:

```
################
################
###########*####
###*######*#####
####**####*#####
######**#*######
########**######
########*#**####
#######*########
######*#########
######*#########
#####*##########
################
################
################
################
```

The above code handles a file for Linux or other unix-like systems. If the text file is needed for the Windows OS you will have to use the sequence `\r\n` as line terminator (so TWO extra chars per line) instead of just `\n`. If instead is a Mac you will need `\r` instead of `\n`.

Opening the file in text mode is not guaranteed to work because (at least formally) you are allowed only to seek at position that was read with `ftell` during a linear scan and you're not allowed to write in the middle of the file.

Comment: (Minor: the OP's example has 15 `#`s, so I think the 16 was already 15*1+1).

Comment: I wasn't trying to draw lines. Literally the only thing I wanted to know was how to delete/overwrite a single character. I know how to write to a file, but write() will insert the characters, right?

Comment: @AndrewPampuch: `write` writes the passed string starting from current `seek` position. If you pass a single char string to `write` then you'll write just a byte. If you need to read a single char just call `read(1)` instead. Note however that partial read/write is supported only for files opened in binary mode.

Comment: Does it write using insert or overwrite mode?

Comment: Also what does `>>` mean on line 19?

Comment: There is no inserting with files. It's always overwritten.

Comment: @AndrewPampuch: `>>` is arithmetic shift right, it's used in the example because it's part of the line-drawing algorithm. `write` always overwrite what is in the file, you cannot insert in a file: you can only overwrite existing content or append to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that write() uses overwrite instead of insert, which makes things a lot more helpful. This code does exactly what I want it to do, minus the read() bit, which is broken for reasons I don't understand.

```
f = open('graph.txt', 'rb+')

while True:
    # TODO: Make an error if X or Y is greater than 15.
    x = input('X = ')
    y = input('Y = ')

    # this thing here finds which character to replace, 
    s = x + (y * 16) # this is how far the tracker seeks
    f.seek(s)
    f.write('*')

    f.seek(0, 0)
    print f.read()
```

Answer (score -2):

Read the entire file as a String. Then, replace whatever character you want at and index of that equation.

```
stringthing = file.read //or whatever the read command is
stringthing[s] = '[whatever your char is]'
[write stringthing to file]
```

helpful?

Comment: That's horrendously inefficient.

Comment: Maybe. Its the same thing that the computer would be doing in the background anyway, though. That's just the solution I know.

Comment: Surely there's a way to use `open()` and `readlines()` to get the line, and then `index` it?

Comment: Maybe, but as I said, what I typed is what the computer would be doing in the background anyway.

Comment: No...I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Basically, just read the file into a string, replace the char you want in that string, and write the string back to the file.